# Nginx と MySQL と php-fpm を再起動するときの順番について

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

Nginx と MySQL と php-fpm の全てを再起動する際、再起動する順番を気にする必要はありますか？
何れを先に行った方が良いとか、ありますか？

環境は、CentOS7です。

Comment: 全部再起動というなら、再起動ではなく、いったん全部停止させてから、システム起動時と同じ順番で起動させれば良いのでは？

Comment: 「OS起動後の順番」は、「Nginx → php-fpm」あるいは「MySQL」起動という流れですか？　起動順番の注意点としては、「Nginx」の後に「php-fpm」起動させることぐらいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実務での考え方を解説していると見做せる以下の記事を見つけました。
[サーバ起動制御 - 闘うITエンジニアの覚え書き](https://www.magata.net/memo/index.php?%A5%B5%A1%BC%A5%D0%B5%AF%C6%B0%C0%A9%B8%E6)
[4.7.1 Web3階層システムを起動する](https://software.fujitsu.com/jp/manual/manualfiles/m120003/b1x10120/01z200/b0120-00-04-07-01.html)

それを当てはめると、システム起動時の順番は以下になるでしょう。
全部再起動する場合は、いったん全部停止してから、この順番で起動していけば良いと思われます。

1. DBサーバー起動  -> MySQL
2. APサーバー起動  -> php-fpm
3. Webサーバー起動 -> Nginx